# LeetCode: Queue Reconstruction by Height C#

Tags: c#, performance, programming-challenge, sorting

https://leetcode.com/problems/queue-reconstruction-by-height/

> Suppose you have a random list of people standing in a queue. Each
>   person is described by a pair of integers \$(h, k)\$, where \$h\$ is the
>   height of the person and \$k\$ is the number of people in front of this
>   person who have a height greater than or equal to \$h\$. Write an
>   algorithm to reconstruct the queue.
>
> Note: The number of people is less than 1,100.
>
> ```
> Example
>
> Input:
> [[7,0], [4,4], [7,1], [5,0], [6,1], [5,2]]
>
> Output:
> [[5,0], [7,0], [5,2], [6,1], [4,4], [7,1]]
> ```

Please review for performance

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SortingQuestions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// https://leetcode.com/problems/queue-reconstruction-by-height/
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class ReconstructQueueTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ReconstructQueueExampleTest()
        {
            int[][] people = new int[6][];
            people[0] = new[] { 7, 0 };
            people[1] = new[] { 4, 4 };
            people[2] = new[] { 7, 1 };
            people[3] = new[] { 5, 0 };
            people[4] = new[] { 6, 1 };
            people[5] = new[] { 5, 2 };

            int[][] expected = new int[6][];
            expected[0] = new[] { 5, 0 };
            expected[1] = new[] { 7, 0 };
            expected[2] = new[] { 5, 2 };
            expected[3] = new[] { 6, 1 };
            expected[4] = new[] { 4, 4 };
            expected[5] = new[] { 7, 1 };
            int[][] res = ReconstructQueueClass.ReconstructQueue(people);
            for (var index = 0; index < res.Length; index++)
            {
                CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected[index], res[index]);
            }
        }
    }

    public class ReconstructQueueClass
    {
        public static int[][] ReconstructQueue(int[][] people)
        {
            int[][] res = new int[people.Length][];
            Array.Sort(people, new PairComparer());

            List<int> list = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < people.Length; i++)
            {
                list.Add(i); //a list of indices 0,1,2,3,4...
                res[i] = new int[2];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < people.Length; i++)
            {
                int index = list[people[i][1]]; //the index in the result is the number of people before you
                res[index][0] = people[i][0];
                res[index][1] = people[i][1];
                list.RemoveAt(people[i][1]); // we remove the index from the list so we keep only the un used ones
            }
            return res;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// sort the people, have min height first
    /// for the same height for example 5,0 and 5,2
    /// 5,2 is before 5,0
    /// </summary>
    public class PairComparer : IComparer<int[]>
    {
        public int Compare(int[] x, int[] y)
        {
            if (x[0] != y[0])
            {
                return x[0] - y[0];// we want min value first
            }
            return y[1] - x[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you marked close let me know what is wrong, I need to learn somehow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### API

I assume it's part of the platform requirements, but `int[]` is a terrible data-structure for storing the `(k, h)` pair, because it could have any length and implies an ordering that doesn't really exist. This should be a small class or immutable struct. (Not a Tuple, because Tuples are structural, and therefore only solve part of the problem).

Even if this was imposed upon me, I would want to map it to something sensible before doing anything else. This mapping would act as a (necessary) validation layer, to check I'm not being given nonsense.

### `ReconstructQueueList`

This should document what it does.

I don't see the point in initialising every element of `res`, when you could just assign them a copy of the existing person array when you set them. This makes the code much tidier. I would move the declaration of `res` toward where it is actually used.

`list` is a completely meaningless variable name. These are the positions in the queue that you have yet to be assigned, so I will call it `positions`; however, I'm sure you can think of something much better. I would create `positions` with `Enumerable.Range(0, people.Length)`, which is more compact and has less scope for errors. I doubt the added overhead will be significant, but feel free to measure it.

### `PairComparer`

`PairComparer` is not a fantastic name for something that sorts people.

It's good that you've given some description of what the custom comparer does. However, I don't understand the description you provide.

I'd prefer to see `x[0].CompareTo(y[0])` instead of `x[0] = y[0]`: it's much clearer what is going on, and it doesn't risk overflowing for numbers with large magnitude.

### Performance

*This section is pretty underwhelming*

If we ignore the problem size limit of 1100 (where did they find that number?), the main performance concern is the `List.Remove(int)` calls, which means this algorithm is quadratic in the worst case (though linear in the best case). You can address this by using a data-structure which allows `log(n)` removal by index. I threw together a simple `OrderedShrinkList`, where removing every has a cost of `n log(n)` and `n` is the number of elements with which it begins, and ran some benchmarks.

Swapping this appears to give a significant performance boost for large problems: it is 10 times faster on a particular random instance of size 200000 [gist of code and results](https://gist.github.com/VisualMelon/9ba073e688f4d5fc651be0b798ef85f7) (it seems to be slower for smaller ones).

Running small problems (e.g. size 1100 and smaller), the potential inefficiency of `List` based method is not immediately revealed, and the overhead of my shoddy `OrderedShrinkList` seems to make it significantly slower. I've run out of energy to keep trying things, but a linked list might actually improve things, because it replacing a linear 'move' with a linear scan, and you can choose at which end to start.

*Note: I did run benchmark for some different seeds, and the general trend was similar, but this isn't the most rigorous test ever.*